# How to get Exchange Mailbox address using folderid property?

Tags: c#-4.0, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have a streaming notifications listener that's subscribed to multiple mailboxes. When a creation notification comes in, I bind to the created item to try to learn more about it.

I try to look at the `ParentDirectoryID.Mailbox` to try to figure out where the item is being created in, but it's null. [The API says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folderid.foldername%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) that the Folder ID and the FolderName/Mailbox properties are mutually exclusive.

So, how do I load the FolderName/Mailbox properties?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should go with the following approach to solve your problem:

1. You can maintain a `List` or `Dictionary` (it's up to you) to store entries of `SubscriptionId` and `MailBox` at the time of subscription, once you received notification, extract `SubscriptionId` and map to your stored `List`/`Dictonary` to get mailbox.

This solution is convenient if you don't need any extra details from Exchange, as is makes fewer calls to Exchange.

2. You can get `MailBox` details from passing `ExtendedPropertyDefination` details and make call using extracted `ItemId` from notification.

I believe you get both of the approaches.